# Gradle task finished with multiple status lines

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

For some reason I get the status of Gradle task like this. I know that this task must fail, but I also get one "SUCCESSFUL" message. Any ideas how I can deal with it, and get back only the fail message ?

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.651 secs

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
Command returned exit status....
11:12:13 AM: External task execution finished 'task123'.
```

Or like this

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.48 secs

 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
 Total time: 2 seconds
 1:02:01 PM: External task execution finished 'clean'.
```

Comment: Do you run two nested gradle builds?

Comment: @Henry no just one. This task is inside a 'build.gradle' of a nested module of the project.